# How to change background color after using 'onkeydown'?

Tags: javascript

I was trying many solutions but none worked.
The problem is where I put the comment.
I trying to do a game which I can change a color of boxes using arrows.

```
var p = 0;
var d0 = document.getElementById('p1').getAttribute('value');
var d1 = document.getElementById('p2').getAttribute('value');
var arraj = [];
arraj.push(d0, d1);

function change() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arraj.length; i++) {
    if (arraj[i] == p) {

      // and here is the problem
      arraj[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}

document.onkeydown = check;

function check(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {

    // left
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    p++;
    change();
    // right
  }
}
```

and HTML

```
    <div class='g' id='p1' value="0">bla</div>
    <div class='g' id='p2' value="1">bla</div>
```

Comment: To begin with, remove the getAttribute chain on both elements.

Comment: When will `arraj[i]==p` be true? One is an element, the other is a number. If you want to compare indexes, then… compare indexes: `i === p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
var p = 0;
var d0 = document.getElementById('p1'); // Remove 'getAttribute('value')' here
var d1 = document.getElementById('p2'); // Remove 'getAttribute('value')' here
var arraj = [];
arraj.push(d0, d1);

function change() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arraj.length; i++) {
    if (arraj[i].getAttribute('value') == p) { // Check for the attribute equality here

      arraj[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}

document.onkeydown = check;

function check(e) {

  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {

    // left
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    p++;
    change();
    // right
  }
}
```

Basically the main issue that you're trying to set background color on element's value attribute and not the element itself.